# Why don't signals change in For loop in Verilog?

Tags: fpga, verilog, simulation, system-verilog, vivado

I am trying to write memory elements using `for` loop.  The `for` loop runs, and I get the value of `k` changing 10 times.  But I am not getting `write` and `select` values changing; they remain constant.  As they are in `while` loop so wouldn't they change?

```
initial 
begin
for(k=0; k<10; k=k+1)
 begin  
  address=k;  
  data_in=(k+k); 
  write=1; select=1;
  #2 write=0; select=0;
 end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You have zero-time glitches on the `write` and `select` signals, but you can't see them in waveforms.  You need to add another delay inside the loop; the single `#2` delay that you have is insufficient.

Here is a runnable example, where I added another `#2` at the end of the `for` loop:

```
module tb;

reg write, select;
integer k, address, data_in;

initial 
begin
    for (k=0; k<10; k=k+1) begin  
        address=k;  
        data_in=(k+k); 
        write=1;
        select=1;
        #2 write=0;
        select=0;
        #2;
    end
end

endmodule
```

The waves show `write` and `select` changing.

[image]

The waveforms were generated from the Synopsys Verdi tool.

Comment: which simulator are you using?

Comment: @Zerox: I used a couple simulators to check this: Cadence and Synopsys.  Why do you ask?  Do you get a different result?  This should work on all simulators.

Comment: Than you for reply....Ut works for me....As modelsim and vivado simulator only gives green waveform by default.It is colourfull so looks amazing

Comment: @Zerox: You're welcome.  I updated my Answer with the tool information.  [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

The write and select are changing, but you are continuously overwriting them. Each time your For Loop iterates, it sets write = 1 and then sets write = 0, this repeats itself 10 times so after the loop has ended both your write and select = 0